# Cyclically dependent Stateless beans in ejb archive jar not getting deployed on JBoss 5.1.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, jboss5.x

I have created an EJB project which has the following java files .
It does not deploy on the JBoss 5.1.0 and spits out deployment error  which is appended after java code below . But the same jar gets deployed on JBoss AS 7.1. 
Why the jar is not getting deployed on JBoss 5.1 ?

*Please note that , the bean implementation BeanA has-a  BeanB's local interface and bean implementation of BeanB has-a BeanA's local interface so it is  a cycle.*

**BeanALocalInterface.java**

```
package com.xyz;    
import javax.ejb.Local;    
    @Local    
public interface BeanALocalInterface {
    public void executeLocal();
}
```

**BeanA.java**

```
package com.xyz;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
@Stateless
public class BeanA implements  BeanALocalInterface {
    @EJB    private BeanBLocalInterface beanBLocalInterface;
    public BeanA() {}
    public void executeLocal() {System.out.println("executing in  BeanA"); beanBLocalInterface.executeLocal();}
    public void executeRemote() {System.out.println("executing in  BeanA"); }
}
```

**BeanBLocalInterface.java**

```
package com.xyz;
import javax.ejb.Local;
@Local
public interface BeanBLocalInterface {
    public void executeLocal();
}
```

**BeanB.java**

```
package com.xyz;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
@Stateless
public class BeanB  implements BeanBLocalInterface  {
    @EJB private BeanALocalInterface localInterface;
    public BeanB() {  }
    public void executeLocal() { localInterface.executeLocal(); }
    public void executeRemote() { System.out.println("executing in  BeanB");}
}
```

**Error Logs while deploying CyclicalBeans.jar in JBOSS 5.1.0**

```
11:59:31,557 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Created KernelDeployment for: CyclicalBeans.jar
11:59:31,557 INFO  [JBossASKernel] installing bean: jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanA,service=EJB3
11:59:31,557 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   with dependencies:
11:59:31,557 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and demands:
11:59:31,573 INFO  [JBossASKernel]      jndi:BeanB/local-com.xyz.BeanBLocalInterface
11:59:31,573 INFO  [JBossASKernel]      jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService
11:59:31,573 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and supplies:
11:59:31,573 INFO  [JBossASKernel]      jndi:BeanA/local-com.xyz.BeanALocalInterface
11:59:31,588 INFO  [JBossASKernel]      jndi:BeanA/local
11:59:31,588 INFO  [JBossASKernel]      Class:com.xyz.BeanARemoteInterface
11:59:31,588 INFO  [JBossASKernel]      jndi:BeanA/remote-com.xyz.BeanARemoteInterface
11:59:31,588 INFO  [JBossASKernel]      Class:com.xyz.BeanALocalInterface
11:59:31,604 INFO  [JBossASKernel]      jndi:BeanA/remote
11:59:31,604 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Added bean(jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanA,service=EJB3) to KernelDeployment of: CyclicalBeans.jar
11:59:31,604 INFO  [JBossASKernel] installing bean: jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanB,service=EJB3
11:59:31,619 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   with dependencies:
11:59:31,619 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and demands:
11:59:31,619 INFO  [JBossASKernel]      jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService
11:59:31,635 INFO  [JBossASKernel]      jndi:BeanA/local-com.xyz.BeanALocalInterface
11:59:31,635 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and supplies:
11:59:31,635 INFO  [JBossASKernel]      Class:com.xyz.BeanBLocalInterface
11:59:31,635 INFO  [JBossASKernel]      jndi:BeanB/local-com.xyz.BeanBLocalInterface
11:59:31,651 INFO  [JBossASKernel]      jndi:BeanB/local
11:59:31,651 INFO  [JBossASKernel]      jndi:BeanB/remote
11:59:31,666 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Added bean(jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanB,service=EJB3) to KernelDeployment of: CyclicalBeans.jar
11:59:31,666 INFO  [EJB3EndpointDeployer] Deploy AbstractBeanMetaData@68f7b23c{name=jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanA,service=EJB3_endpoint bean=org.jboss.ejb3.endpoint.deployers.impl.EndpointImpl properties=[container] constructor=null autowireCandidate=true}
11:59:31,666 INFO  [EJB3EndpointDeployer] Deploy AbstractBeanMetaData@3b870737{name=jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanB,service=EJB3_endpoint bean=org.jboss.ejb3.endpoint.deployers.impl.EndpointImpl properties=[container] constructor=null autowireCandidate=true}
11:59:31,744 WARN  [HDScanner] Failed to process changes
org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanA,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanA,service=EJB3>" (should be in state "Described", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:BeanB/local-com.xyz.BeanBLocalInterface' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanA,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanA,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Configured", but is actually in state "PreInstall")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanB,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanB,service=EJB3>" (should be in state "Described", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:BeanA/local-com.xyz.BeanALocalInterface' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanB,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanB,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Configured", but is actually in state "PreInstall")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanA,service=EJB3>" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:BeanB/local-com.xyz.BeanBLocalInterface' **
  Deployment "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:jar=CyclicalBeans.jar,name=BeanB,service=EJB3>" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:BeanA/local-com.xyz.BeanALocalInterface' **

        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:993)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:939)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:873)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.checkComplete(MainDeployerAdapter.java:128)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:369)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@IgnoreDependency annotation on injected Beans will resolve this issue. Please Modify BeanA.java and BeanB.java as follows:

BeanA.java

```
package com.xyz;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.IgnoreDependency;
@Stateless
public class BeanA implements  BeanALocalInterface {
    @IgnoreDependency
    @EJB(name="ejb/BeanBLocalInterface")    private BeanBLocalInterface beanBLocalInterface;
    public BeanA() {}
    public void executeLocal() {System.out.println("executing in  BeanA"); beanBLocalInterface.executeLocal();}
    public void executeRemote() {System.out.println("executing in  BeanA"); }
}
```

BeanB.java

```
package com.xyz;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.IgnoreDependency;

@Stateless
public class BeanB  implements BeanBLocalInterface  {
    @IgnoreDependency
    @EJB(name="ejb/BeanALocalInterface ") private BeanALocalInterface localInterface;
    public BeanB() {  }
    public void executeLocal() { localInterface.executeLocal(); }
    public void executeRemote() { System.out.println("executing in  BeanB");}
}
```

I derived my solution from the following question answer link . [answer link](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/110283?tstart=0)

Comment: A bug similar to this problem : [EJBTHREE-1603](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/EJBTHREE-1603) -> Cyclic @EJB dependency doesn't work anymore